# How to get to the snowcraft minigame?

Tags: android, final-fantasy-2

In Final Fantasy 2, there is a hidden [memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game)) minigame that you can access once you get the [snowcraft](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Snowcraft). The original version of FF2 didn't have the minigame, but other versions do.

However, I haven't been able to find any instructions on how to access the minigame on the Android version of FF2. It doesn't make sense that it wouldn't be there when it is present in both the PSP version on which the Android version is based and in the iOS version (why have it on one mobile platform but not another?).

How can I get to the snowcraft minigame?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Minigame)

> In the Dawn of Souls version, the player must hold down A and keep pressing the B button. Similarly, in the 20th Anniversary release, the player must hold down X-button and keep pressing Circle-button 22 times. In the iOS version, players have to shake the device to activate the minigame.

I'd guess that the Android activation is the same as iOS.